# In a React/Redux project how to make Typescript aware of property passed by redux's connect decorator?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Given the following components, I get an error about a missing `isUpdating` prop.  How do I fix that?

> Error:(87, 27) TS2322:Type '{ name: "Fred"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Reado...'.
>     Type '{ name: "Fred"; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
>       Property 'isUpdating' is missing in type '{ name: "Fred"; }'.

```
interface ContaineeProps {
  name: string;
  isUpdating: string;
}

const Containee = (props: ContaineeProps) => <span>{props.name}</span>;

interface MapStateToProps {
  isUpdating: boolean;
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ isUpdating: state.years.yearsUpdating });

const ConnectedContainee = connect<MapStateToProps, null, ContaineeProps>(mapStateToProps)(Containee);


interface Container {
  name: string;
}

class Container extends React.Component<Container, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <ConnectedContainee name="Fred" />
    )
  }
}
```

edit: This question is more about best practices in a redux/react/typescript application and less about the reason for this error.  Do I always have to have required props type information specified in two places (props interface for the component, and the interface for the mapStateToProps function)?

Comment: What is VehiclesFormProps?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Well crap, I thought I did such a careful job copy/pasting/editing a simplified example from my actual components.  Turns out that actually I suck!  (fixed my example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error you're receiving is correct. Given your `ContaineeProps` contains a property `isUpdating`, your component expects to be passed this property when you use it.

e.g. `<ConnectedContainee name="Fred" isUpdating="testing" />`

Given your question, I am wondering whether`isUpdating` should be in `ContaineeProps` at all? If it's not then simply remove it and the compile error should go away.

If it is intended to be there then I would recommend giving it a different name as you already have an `isUpdating` prop in your `MapStateToProps` interface.

**Update**

If I understand your comment correctly you've added the `isUpdating` prop to your `ContaineeProps` to be able to access it within your component. To do this you don't need to add the property to both prop interfaces, I don't actually think that would work...

What you need to do is combine your interfaces so your component can have access to both interfaces that contain props passed in from parent components and props mapped in from redux.

Here's an example:

```
interface AllProps extends MapStateToProps, ContaineeProps {}

const Containee = (props: AllProps) => <span>{props.name} {props.isUpdating}</span>;
```

or

```
const Containee = (props: ContaineeProps & MapStateToProps) => <span>{props.name} {props.isUpdating}</span>;
```

`props.isUpdating` now refers to the property mapped in from the redux store. If you wanted to also store the `isUpdating` value locally you would use the components local state.

Comment: The `Containee` component _requires_ the `isUpdating` prop.  At no point will it ever be "manually" passed to it, it will always come from the redux store via the call to connect.  I understand that I can remove the prop in `ContaineeProps`, but then I've got to maintain type information for the component in two places...`MapStateToProps` and `ContaineeProps`.  If that is the way it is normally done in a redux/react/typescript application, so be it, it just seems suboptimal.

Comment: @DustinWyatt, I have updated my answer to reflect your comment. Hope this helps.